# How to set a prompt for second time when user has clicked Don't allow for permissions the first time?

Tags: ios, ios7, calendar, user-permissions

I want to add a prompt when user access the calendar second time, when initially user has clicked Don't Allow for the first access permissions for calendar.

```
// For iOS 6.0 and later
EKEventStore *_eventStore [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    // handle access here
}];

EKEventStore *_reminderStore [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[_reminderStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    // handle access here
}];
```

This piece of code is for the first time when user is being asked for the permissions, can anyone please tell me, what to do when user has clicked Don't allow after this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the second request inside the first request's block.

So it would look like this:

```
// For iOS 6.0 and later
EKEventStore *_eventStore [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            // handle access here
        }];
    }
}];
```

Also keep in mind that initializing an EKEventStore is expensive. Try to only use one instance of it. That information and more can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1)